# most DRY way to redirect unauthenticated user to login screen in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm currently starting out with Ember and have managed to create a modal login screen using bootstrap's modal class.

I know how to display the login screen and I want to integrate it with routing so that with each transition the current loggedIn state of the user is checked and if the user is not logged in, redirect them to the entry page and pop up the login screen.

I'm looking for the most 'Dont-Repeat-Yourself' way of cross cutting this requirement, can any ember experts please assist me?

Answer (score 1):

One approach of doing this is by creating a special route (or override the `Ember.Route` through `reopen`) for protected routes and a public route for non protected routes. Then extend these routes.

```
/*Ember.Route.reopen({*//*to globally protect all routes*/
App.ProtectedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function() {

//if no promise used and isAuthenticated returns a boolean
//        if (!isAuthenticated()) {
//            this.transitionTo("login");
//        }

//if promise used and isAuthenticated returns a promise
        var self = this;
/*using the error part of then if error code is returned from server, otherwise the succes part could be used check the data value and decide the outcome*/
        return isAuthenticated().then(null, function(data) {
            self.transitionTo("login");
            return Ember.RSVP.resolve(data);
        });
    }
});

/*to be used for views that do not require authentication*/
App.PublicRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    /*skip default Route's security check*/
    beforeModel: function() {
    }
});
```

A protected route would be,

```
App.FirstRoute = App.ProtectedRoute.extend();
```

A public route would be,

```
App.SecondRoute = App.PublicRoute.extend();
```

The `isAuthenticated` with promise could be something like

```
function isAuthenticated(){
/*calling server to check if authenticated, if not authenticated server returns error code i.e. 500*/
return $.ajax({});
}
```

Comment: Where would i define my 'isAuthenticated' function? outside of everything?

Comment: @thenaglecode usually i place that kind of code in specific controllers (eg. `App.AuthenticationController`) without any `route` or `view` associated just for business logic, otherwise a global function will also suffice.

Comment: So Like a computed property?

Comment: @thenaglecode actually just a function. Here are two quick examples of what i'm describing. The first with a global function that could be placed anywhere e.g. inside a specific lib related file (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xarebuwi/1/edit), the second using an `ember` controller that holds business logic in order to have access to the awesome `ember` object model/capabilities (http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/) if required (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bubogife/1/edit).

Comment: I'd also recommend taking a look at ember-simple-auth.  It's very easy to use and even if you don't use it you can see how they handle authentication: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth