# Login in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I implemented a login with the help of embercasts and some posts of stackoverflow.

It works but it feels bad, because of the use of `ApplicationController` together with `LoginController`.

The login should get me two things done.

1. hiding GUI elements, which aren't needed/available
2. preventing the use of specific routes

To hide the elements I needed to check the login state in my templates. So I created a `loggedIn` attribute for the `ApplicationController`. I don't know how to do this different, but it feels like a global (bad) variable.

The AC also implements the logout, which is needed on the whole page, but still seems bad too, since it uses the LC in the background.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    loggedIn: false,

    actions: {
        logout: function() {
            var loginCtrl = this.controllerFor('login');

            loginCtrl.set('token', null);

            this.set('loggedIn', false);

            this.transitionToRoute('landingpage');
        }
    }
});
```

This is the `ApplicationRoute` it also uses the LC for checking the state.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(ctrl) {
        var loginCtrl = this.controllerFor('login');

        if(loginCtrl.get('token')) {
            ctrl.set('loggedIn', true);
        } else {
            ctrl.set('loggedIn', false);
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a better way to do this, without coupling the AC and LC?
Like getting the login state from LC in every template.

Or should I just drop the LC and implement this logic in the AC, because it's needed everywhere?

Comment: My opinion is that there is nothing wrong with ur approach. Controllers will sometimes need another controller. Enber even provides a 'need' property for that. http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with blessenm it is completely fine to call controllers from other controllers.

In addition following the oop paradigm I suggest a little higher cohesion by specifying  the login/logout/authentication responsibilities to the `LoginController` only.

Thus the token would be part of the LC as well as its maintenance eg checking if logged in through a function, unsetting it through a logout function etc. Then there can be a base `PrivateRoute` (or reopen the `Em.Route`), that will use this controller. All other routes will extend from this route, if they require a logged in user. Logout action can be handled by `ApplicationController` but always call the logout function of `LC`.

Rough example of the routing given here, but no special controller had been used for brevity

[most DRY way to redirect unauthenticated user to login screen in ember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380423/most-dry-way-to-redirect-unauthenticated-user-to-login-screen-in-ember/23381339#23381339)